# Tagging and exploding in php

Tags: php, mysql

In my index file I get data from the database using this function (which is in another file):

```
function get_all_threads($link, $start)
{
    $threads = select_Query("SELECT thread.title, thread.id as t_id,
                           thread.content, author.username, author.id as a_id,
                           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.name ORDER BY tags.name DESC SEPARATOR ',') AS tags
                           FROM thread JOIN thread_tags ON thread.id = thread_tags.thread_id
                           JOIN tags ON thread_tags.tag_id = tags.id
                           INNER JOIN author on author.id = thread.author_id
                           GROUP BY thread.id DESC
                           LIMIT $start, 30", $link);     

    return $threads;
}
```

The code in my index file is as follows:

```
    $threads = get_all_threads($link, $start);
    include FORUM_ROOT . 'html/main/threads.html.php';
```

In threads.html.php

```
<?php foreach ($threads as $thread): ?>

<h1><?php echo $thread['title']; ?></h1>
<?php echo $thread['content']; ?>
<?php echo $thread['tags']; ?> <!-- All of these appear as one -->

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

As you can see I get the threads, their authors and their tags. However I use GROUP_CONCAT for tags, so when I want to make each individual tag a link, such as in threads.html.php:

```
<a href="?tag=<?php echo $thread['tags']; ?>" > 
   <?php echo $thread['tags']; ?>  
</a>
```

All the tags appear as one link, (e.g. if the tags were apple, orange, banana they would appear as [apple, orange, banana](http://apple) and not [apple](http://apple), [orange](http://orange), [banana](http://banana)):

I know to split up these tags I can use explode and then iterate over each as follows:

```
<?php $tags = array(); 
$tags = explode(',', $thread['tags']);
?>


(Tagged: 
<?php foreach ($tags as $tag): ?>
<a href="/tag?=<?php echo $tag;?>"><?php echo $tag; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>)
```

However I would then have to do this in threads.html.php and I want to keep presentation code seperate.

Is there a neater way of doing this in index.php? Also to iterate over each thread and exploding each tag will take too long for threads that are more than 30.

**Edit:**

My table structure is as follows:

thread, author_threads, author, tag, thread_tags, reply and author_replies

[1](http://apple): http://apple, orange, banana

Comment: can you add your db table structure

Comment: I’d prefer a simplification of the problem … if possible.

Comment: I don’t think `GROUP_CONCAT` is SQL standard … which DBS do you use?

Comment: Why do you use group_concat in the first place? I see you use a lot of joins to get the tags for a thread … Oh, I think I get it now. You have a thread with potentially several tags, and when printing the tags you want to link them!? That’s simple: Don’t do it in 1 query. Get the threads in one query, then get the tags for a thread in another.

Comment: @Kissaki GROUP_CONCAT is MySQL function.

Comment: On the front page though, I want to show what tags a certain thread has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat `get_all_threads` as part of model - black box - you don't need to know HOW data are fetched (is it SQL query, xml files or external api call). You are intrested in data, nothing more.

As far it is not possible to get multiple tags for one thread via SQL query. Even if you remove `GROUP_CONCAT` you will get a bunch of records for one thread, which also gonna need parsing in some way. But according to first paragraph, you should parse data in your function.

```
function get_all_threads($link, $start)
{
    $threads = select_Query("SELECT thread.title, thread.id as t_id,..");

    //PHP 5.3   
    array_walk($threads, function(&$thread) {
        $thread['tags'] = explode(',', $thread['tags']);
    });

    //PHP < 5.3
    foreach ($threads as &$thread) {
        $thread['tags'] = explode(',', $thread['tags']);
    }


    return $threads;
}
```

When you do it that way, your presentation code will be clean.

Comment: That code requires PHP 5.3 as it use anonymous function. Added version without it. But upgrading to PHP 5.3 recommended ;)

Comment: I'm using ubuntu Karmic Koala,  so I'll have to upgrade that before I can get 5.3

Answer (score 0):

You want to get and print several tags for each thread. So why do you do it in one query? Instead of doing one massive query you would:

```
SELECT thread.title, thread.id as t_id, thread.content,
       author.username, author.id as a_id,
INNER JOIN author ON author.id = thread.author_id
ORDER BY thread.id DESC
LIMIT $start, 30
```

and for each thread a

```
SELECT tags.name
FROM thread_tags
WHERE thread_tags.thread_id == $id
```

Store those in a datastructure and pass it to your presentation templates (like you do now with your threadlist).

(Holy crap, that was a complicated query …
Looks much better now as well, right? And so much easier to read and understand!)

Btw, what’s with the `GROUP BY thread.id DESC`? I do hope your ID is UNIQUE, or better yet a PRIMARY KEY! No GROUP BY necessary then!

Comment: I actually dont know why the group by is there, I'm using primary keys, removing it now

Comment: The problem I have is I wont always know how many threads I will be getting, see the limit.

Comment: And what’s the problem about that? Get the tags for all topics you do get.